# SIGABRT error in Xamarin.Forms app

Tags: xamarin.forms, hockeyapp

I have a Xamarin.Forms application that we are ready to deploy to production but I keep getting this SIGABRT error.
I've setup a HockeyApp to monitor any crash that may occur.
It seems that this error keeps on appearing crash or not.
I've included the upper portion of the stack trace that I don't know how to interpret.
Can any body help me interpret what this is?
Thank you

---

```
Incident Identifier: C2FA8822-C1D4-4ECA-BD30-2D38D10A7AF2
CrashReporter Key:   90F6BDB6-4B7A-4F69-BA47-74027B6E607D
Hardware Model:      iPhone7,2
Process:         MyCase.iOS [1687]
Path:            /var/containers/Bundle/Application/23343C73-BA08-4F6F-8FD9-99472E20F2A3/MyCase.iOS.app/MyCase.iOS
Identifier:      <Bundle Id> (omitted for privacy reasons)
Version:         2.93 (2.93)
Code Type:       ARM-64
Parent Process:  ??? [1]

Date/Time:       2016-09-20T00:01:29Z
Launch Time:     2016-09-19T22:20:17Z
OS Version:      iPhone OS 9.3.5 (13G36)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  SIGABRT
Exception Codes: #0 at 0x181ef011c
Crashed Thread:  0

Application Specific Information:
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'This app can't run in background'

Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                       0x0000000182356db0 0x18222c000 + 1224112
1   libobjc.A.dylib                      0x00000001819bbf80 0x1819b4000 + 32640
2   CoreFoundation                       0x0000000182356c80 0x18222c000 + 1223808
3   Foundation                           0x0000000182cdc154 0x182c38000 + 672084
4   TestLib.dylib                        0x00000001016b7d88 0x1016b0000 + 32136
5   UIKit                                0x000000018777201c 0x1874a4000 + 2940956
6   UIKit                                0x0000000187777ba4 0x1874a4000 + 2964388
7   UIKit                                0x0000000187777a80 0x1874a4000 + 2964096
8   UIKit                                0x000000018776170c 0x1874a4000 + 2873100
9   UIKit                                0x0000000187761394 0x1874a4000 + 2872212
10  FrontBoardServices                   0x0000000183cf77ac 0x183cd0000 + 161708
11  FrontBoardServices                   0x0000000183cf7618 0x183cd0000 + 161304
12  FrontBoardServices                   0x0000000183cf79c8 0x183cd0000 + 162248
13  CoreFoundation                       0x000000018230d09c 0x18222c000 + 921756
14  CoreFoundation                       0x000000018230cb30 0x18222c000 + 920368
15  CoreFoundation                       0x000000018230a830 0x18222c000 + 911408
16  CoreFoundation                       0x0000000182234c50 0x18222c000 + 35920
17  GraphicsServices                     0x0000000183b1c088 0x183b10000 + 49288
18  UIKit                                0x0000000187522088 0x1874a4000 + 516232
19  MyCase.iOS                           0x0000000100d7a514 0x100020000 + 14001428
20  MyCase.iOS                           0x0000000100ccb40c 0x100020000 + 13284364
21  MyCase.iOS                           0x0000000100ccb3cc 0x100020000 + 13284300
22  MyCase.iOS                           0x0000000100295454 0x100020000 + 2577492
23  MyCase.iOS                           0x0000000100729554 0x100020000 + 7378260
24  MyCase.iOS                           0x000000010018f1c4 0x100020000 + 1503684
25  MyCase.iOS                           0x00000001001f7f94 0x100020000 + 1933204
26  MyCase.iOS                           0x00000001001fc948 0x100020000 + 1952072
27  MyCase.iOS                           0x0000000100294da0 0x100020000 + 2575776
28  MyCase.iOS                           0x00000001013cf510 0x100020000 + 20641040
29  ???                                  0x0000000181dd28b8 0x0 + 0

Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib               0x0000000181ef011c 0x181ed4000 + 114972
1   libsystem_c.dylib                    0x0000000181e61dc8 0x181e00000 + 400840
2   MyCase.iOS                           0x0000000100135014 0x100020000 + 1134612
3   CoreFoundation                       0x0000000182357138 0x18222c000 + 1225016
4   libobjc.A.dylib                      0x00000001819bc23c 0x1819b4000 + 33340
5   MyCase.iOS                           0x0000000100122d50 0x100020000 + 1060176
6   libc++abi.dylib                      0x00000001819aef44 0x181994000 + 110404
7   libc++abi.dylib                      0x00000001819aeb10 0x181994000 + 109328
8   libobjc.A.dylib                      0x00000001819bc120 0x1819b4000 + 33056
9   CoreFoundation                       0x0000000182234cf8 0x18222c000 + 36088
10  GraphicsServices                     0x0000000183b1c088 0x183b10000 + 49288
11  UIKit                                0x0000000187522088 0x1874a4000 + 516232
12  MyCase.iOS                           0x0000000100d7a514 0x100020000 + 14001428
13  MyCase.iOS                           0x0000000100ccb40c 0x100020000 + 13284364
14  MyCase.iOS                           0x0000000100ccb3cc 0x100020000 + 13284300
15  MyCase.iOS                           0x0000000100295454 0x100020000 + 2577492
16  MyCase.iOS                           0x0000000100729554 0x100020000 + 7378260
17  MyCase.iOS                           0x000000010018f1c4 0x100020000 + 1503684
18  MyCase.iOS                           0x00000001001f7f94 0x100020000 + 1933204
19  MyCase.iOS                           0x00000001001fc948 0x100020000 + 1952072
20  MyCase.iOS                           0x0000000100294da0 0x100020000 + 2575776
21  MyCase.iOS                           0x00000001013cf510 0x100020000 + 20641040
22  ???                                  0x0000000181dd28b8 0x0 + 0
```

Answer (score 0):

I've have had the same error before HockeyApp NuGet package or any NuGet package can have the same error I am not sure if it a Linking error, try to turn off the linker ("Don't link") if that does not work try to use a different version of HockeyApp (3.7.1.0) works fine for me.

The problem may persist tho, if you are handling code inside the AppDelegate or the MainActivity check the App lifecycle (OnResume, OnStart, OnSleep and so on).

I can see in the logs: "This app can't run in background" So verify and double check if your code is handling correctly the App Lifecycle and transitions, it may be related to a lot of things (notifications, components, NuGets, Lifecycle, threads, async/await calls)

Hope this helps.